# Windows registry HKCR merging rules

Tags: windows, com, registry

From what I understand **HKCR** is a view merging keys from both **HKCU** and **HKLM**.

But I have a key in **HKCU**:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{8A49257F-D5E9-47DB-B87D-E09EBAF199AE}]
```

Which is not reflected in **HKCR** at:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{8A49257F-D5E9-47DB-B87D-E09EBAF199AE}]
```

But if I put the key in **HKLM**:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{8A49257F-D5E9-47DB-B87D-E09EBAF199AE}]
```

it's correctly reflected in **HKCR**.

Which rule(s) am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because HKCU does not support Wow6432Node.

Comment: @RaymondChen: according to the documentation it does, though only for CLSID and a few other subkeys, not for all of SOFTWARE.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: My misread. It doesn't support it  in the place you put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct path is

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID
```

rather than

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID
```

so this is likely to be your problem.  However, rather than using hardcoded Wow6432Node paths, it would be preferable to write the key to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID
```

with the `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` option.  That way if the redirection scheme changes in the future your app will still work properly.

Also note that on Vista some keys in `CLSID` are reflected, i.e., copied automatically between the 32-bit and 64-bit views.  See [Registry Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384235%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in MSDN.  You may need to take this into account.

Comment: Thanks, you're perfectly right, it correctly works under `Classes\Wow6432Node`; but I don't get where in the documentation this behavior is specified (I'm on Win 7). And I'm writing some ".reg" files, not using the registry API, so I can't benefit from the registry redirector.

Comment: Hum in fact what is misleading is the fact that `HKLM\Sofware\Classes\Wow6432Node` is mirrored in `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes`. I've always believed that the second path was the only one. So now it makes more sense, and is indeed consistent with the HKCU tree.

Comment: That's because all of HKLM\Software is mirrored, whereas HKCU\Software isn't.  It isn't specified in the documentation because using `Wow6432Node` is unsupported, and that's why you should use `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` instead.